# what ppa should be removed to not get apt-get update error

Tags: apt, ppa

When I try to update I get this error. I am not sure why am I getting this error.

```
Fetched 424 kB in 46s (9,190 B/s)                                              
W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org  Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5A7D1D38BEB6D886
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexeftimie/ppa/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexeftimie/ppa/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexeftimie/ppa/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

[Please see this picture and help me to solve this above error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WA4Ki.png)

Comment: It is not because of wily-backports but because of the PPAs. Look at [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists) to know how to solve this.

Comment: @Ron  I have update my question and also added a picture. Please help me to spot error. I can't get it fixed.

Comment: The warnings (the three 404s) are a known bug in the upstream. Apparently the person (alexeftmie) managing the PPAs has been having some problems and his PPAs are unreachable. Try removing the first PPA using `ppa-purge`.

Comment: Remove all the lines containing opensuse and alexeftimie. Did you even go through the link I posted?

Comment: @Ron i read what you posted but I wasn't removing the ppa's I was just unticking them. Hoping it would fix. Finally it worked, completely removed them